# Why, while reading a file line by line, do I have these printed?

Tags: bash, glob

Using bash, I am reading a file line by line with the following code:

```
for entry in "$2"*; do
    while read LINE
        do 
        #handler $LINE
        echo $LINE
    done < $entry
done
```

Where `$2` is the file name. (you can find the file here: https://gist.github.com/floriancastelain/2a956dcd01174ed8c207f93d7e4645f2)

However, I expected the output of echo to be only the lines of the file. But instead I got this (sorry for the image, but formatting the console output is a pain in the ass) :

[image]

Note the elements such as `/bin /boot /cdrom /dev /etc /home /initrd.img /initrd.img.old /lib` or `jersey mdoc.bash util`. Where do these come from and how to avoid them ?

Comment: @oguzismail, that's iterating over input filenames -- looks perfectly reasonable. The problem is use of `echo $LINE` rather than `echo "$LINE"`

Comment: @Charles ngl never encountered such a problem with echo before

Comment: @oguzismail, see [BashPitfalls #14](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo)